# Using the Http headers to unmarshall a response with spray-client

Tags: scala, http-headers, spray, spray-client

I'm using `spray-client` to access a REST service. Part of the data returned by the server is in the http response headers (the rest is in the response body).

In order to be able to unmarshall the response, I am using an `Unmarshaller`. However, the unmarshaller can only access the response body (as an instance of `HttpEntity`) and all headers seems to be unaccessible at this stage.

Here is the current pipeline and the unmarshaller codes:

```
  implicit val IDsUnmarshaller = 
    Unmarshaller[List[ID]](MediaTypes.`text/plain`) {
      case HttpEntity.NonEmpty(contentType, data) => 
        data.asString.split("\n").toList.map( ID(_) )
    }

  val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[List[ID]] = (
    encode(Gzip)
    ~> sendReceive
    ~> decode(Deflate)
    ~> unmarshal[List[ID]]
  )
```

Is there anyway to access them when unmarshalling ? Is there any work around ?

Comment: If you provide a `FromResponseUnmarshaller` instead of a plain `Unmarshaller` you also have access to the headers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know if there is any factory method for creating `FromResponseUnmarshaller` ?

Comment: See this file for ways to create `FromResponseUnmarshallers`: https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/unmarshalling/Deserializer.scala

Comment: E.g. you can provide an implicit function `HttpResponse => List[ID]` and that should be picked up.

Comment: Thanks @jrudolph, it works and that's exactly what I was looking for. If you copy it in an answer I will acept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide a FromResponseUnmarshaller instead of a plain Unmarshaller you also have access to the headers.

See this file for ways to create FromResponseUnmarshallers: https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/unmarshalling/Deserializer.scala

E.g. you can provide an implicit function `HttpResponse => List[ID]` and that should be picked up.